# Searching from a sorted array in less than O(log(n)) running time

Tags: c, algorithm, search, binary-search

I am using binary search to search a number from a sorted array of numbers in O(log(n)) time. My C function for search is as follows:

```
search(int array[],int size,int search)
 {
 int first=0;
 int last=size-1;
 int middle = (first+last)/2;
   while( first <= last )
   {
      if ( array[middle] < search )
         first = middle + 1;    
      else if ( array[middle] == search ) 
      {
         printf("%d found at location %d.\n", search, middle+1);
         break;
      }
      else
         last = middle - 1;

      middle = (first + last)/2;
   }
   if ( first > last )
      printf("Not found! %d is not present in the list.\n", search);
}
```

Here `size` is the size of array and `search` is the number to search.
Is there any way to perform the search in less complexity then the above program?

Comment: (1) `there must be a way`  - why? (2) If your array is in RAM, in 32 bits systems, `log_2(n) < 32`. Is it that bad? (3) Are you looking for better asymptotic complexity [`Omega(logn)`] or an implementation with better constants?

Comment: Standard C defines [`bsearch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bsearch.html) which searches the array in O(log(n)) time. I believe you can't do better with comparison based search.

Comment: All comparisons based algorithm have a lower bound of logn. @pmg proofs have been made to back up your belief.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4057258/1009831).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565583/what-is-the-tight-lower-time-complexity-bound-for-searching-in-a-sorted-array as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use a hash table. It should be faster in the average case.

Comment: which means it is not a sorted array anymore.

Comment: @UmNyobe: You can store both, a sorted array **and** a `hashmap:key->index`. Correct me if I miss something, but I don't think it will make other sorted array ops assymptotically slower as well. I don't think it is a good solution, but it is possible.

Comment: @amit yes. The OP should clarify more what he needs. I am not the downvoter though